# Alias path can't be recognized in Jest

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ts-jest, tsconfig

I recently created an alias path to import my components. My issue is that jest can't resolve the alias path. For example, `Cannot find module '@/components/comment/CommentDeleteDialog' from 'src/__tests__/components/CommentDeleteDialog.test.tsx'`.

```
import { render, fireEvent, screen } from '@testing-library/react'
import '@testing-library/jest-dom'
> import CommentDeleteDialog from '@/components/comment/CommentDeleteDialog'

...
```

Below is my folder structure.

```
├── jest.config.js
├── tsconfig.json
├── package.json
├── src
│   ├── __tests__
│   ├── assets
│   ├── components
│   ├── config.ts
│   ├── constants
│   ├── contexts
│   ├── hooks
│   ├── index.tsx
│   ├── layouts
│   ├── pages
│   ├── react-app-env.d.ts
│   ├── socket.ts
│   ├── styles
│   ├── types
│   └── utils
├── webpack.config.js
├── worker.js
└── wrangler.toml
```

Here is my tsconfig screen shot
[image]

Also my jest.config
[image]

I am not sure where is the error coming from. Is there any missing in the structure?

Comment: I also use this platform but still got the error. `` const { pathsToModuleNameMapper } = require('ts-jest')
const { compilerOptions } = require('./tsconfig')

/** @type {import('ts-jest').JestConfigWithTsJest} */
module.exports = {
    preset: 'ts-jest',
    testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
    roots: ['<rootDir>'],
    modulePaths: [compilerOptions.baseUrl], // <-- This will be set to 'baseUrl' value
    moduleNameMapper: pathsToModuleNameMapper(compilerOptions.paths /*, { prefix: '<rootDir>/' } */),
  
}
``